# reduction in the elements of list

Tags: coq

I have natural number list. After reduction of one element from the list, I want to prove the following relation.

```
Theorem reduce_elements:forall (n:nat) (l:list nat),
 (length (n :: l) =? 0) = false->
 (length l =? 0) = false.
```

Answer (score 1):

This statement does not hold:

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.

Theorem reduce_elements:forall (n:nat) (l:list nat),
 (length (n :: l) =? 0) = false->
 (length l =? 0) = false.
Admitted.

Goal False.
pose proof (reduce_elements 0 nil eq_refl).
simpl in H.
congruence.
Qed.
```

I've noticed you've come to Stack Overflow a few times asking help to prove false statements. I suggest you try to sketch those proofs on paper before trying to solve them with Coq: it will help you understand your problem better.

Comment: I am trying to close false statement by inserting right statement. Like a<=b(I know this is some false statement).Correct statement is b<=a. On contradiction basis how to relate these? One way is to prove  a>b.Some other way that could be helpful in this situation?